# How to disable Carousel Page scrolling in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, carousel, renderer

Using a custom renderer one can disable the swiping gesture of an `CarouselPage` on `iOS` like so:

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CarouselPage), typeof(CustomCarouselPageRenderer))]
namespace App.iOS
{
    public class CustomCarouselPageRenderer : CarouselPageRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            UIView view = this.NativeView;
            UIScrollView scrollView = (UIKit.UIScrollView)view.Subviews[0];
            scrollView.ScrollEnabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

How to accomplish the same on Android?

```
using Android.Content;
using XamFormsApp.Droid.Renderers;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CarouselPage), typeof(CustomCarouselPageRenderer))]
namespace StixApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomCarouselPageRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<CarouselPage>
    {
        public CustomCarouselPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CarouselPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var view = this.RootView;
            X
            X
        }
    }
}
```

There appears to be no way to access `Subviews` in the same way. One can access `Children` like so

```
Android.Views.View view = (Android.Views.View)GetChildAt(i);
```

How to know which `Child` is `ScrollView` if any?

Using a loop to check for this, like so,

```
for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; ++i)
{
    Android.Views.View view = (Android.Views.View)GetChildAt(i);
    if (view is ScrollView)
    {
    }
}
```

Yields the following: "*The given expression is never of the provided (`ScrollView`) type*"

So! How to disable `CarouselPage` swipe/scrolling as is done in `iOS` quite elegantly?

**UPDATE**: Please see [sample solution](https://github.com/jvhgamer/CarouselSample).

Comment: Thanks. Your sample solution is working like a charm

Comment: @Janwilx72 My pleasure. Glad to hear it's helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things.

For **Android** the view you are looking for is not a `ScrollView` but a `ViewPager`.

This can be found under the index 0 with the **GetChildAt** method.

Also, why are you using `VisualElementRenderer<CarouselPage>` as the parent class of your `CustomCarouselPageRenderer`. Instead use the `CarouselPageRenderer` as you did with iOS.

One last thing is that on **Android** the Scroll of a ViewPager cannot be disabled. To get this behavior you can listen to the **Touch** event. Setting the Handled property of **TouchEventArgs** to **true** will prevent the scrolling from happening.

Your whole class would look something like:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CarouselPage), typeof(CustomCarouselPageRenderer))]
namespace StixApp.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomCarouselPageRenderer : CarouselPageRenderer
    {
        private bool _canScroll = false;

        public CustomCarouselPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        public CustomCarouselPageRenderer()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CarouselPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (this.ChildCount > 0  && this.GetChildAt(0) is ViewPager viewPager)
            {
                viewPager.Touch -= ViewPagerTouched;
                viewPager.Touch += ViewPagerTouched;
            }
        }

        private void ViewPagerTouched(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !_canScroll;
        }
    }
}
```

Just change the value of **_canScroll** to true to allow the scrolling.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much. Second - `e.Handled = false` doesn't fully block the swipe action. It seems to allow very small movements. Will investigate. Also - removing the `e.Handled = false` assignment seems to be the same behavior.

Comment: Would it be more viable to override the [Xamarin.Forms renderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/CarouselPageRenderer.cs) and use a custom [ViewPager](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5145/nonswipeableviewpager)? Note: this is where the `VisualElementRenderer<CarouselPage>` as my parent class came from.

Comment: I went for it and it works as expected. Is [this](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d27eb4da7a2dc4c7599f701aba7eaf8d20190405182432/5beb2d) within best practice guidelines? The only way to use a custom `ViewPager` was to copy the Xamarin.Forms `CarouselPageRenderer` and use our own `CustomViewPager` within. The sample is fully operational with all code used to disable swiping for `CarouselPage` on `Android`.

Comment: @jtth Wow nice work. Yes, it's acceptable to override any Class to get the behavior you are expecting.

Comment: Note: for future visitors, link reference above `this` expires soon/has expired. See op for github link.

Answer (score 1):

Overridden `Methods` in `ViewPager` class:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager : ViewPager
{    
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public override bool ExecuteKeyEvent(KeyEvent ev)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Changes to `CarouselPageRenderer`:

In `class` declaration:

```
public class MyCarouselPageRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<CarouselPage>
{
    NonSwipeableViewPager _viewPager;
}
```

In `OnElementChanged`:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CarouselPage> e)
{
    _viewPager = new NonSwipeableViewPager(Context);
}
```

Note: `CarouselPageAdapter`, `CarouselPageRenderer`, `MeasureSpecFactory`, `ObjectJavaBox`, and `PageContainer` all had to be copied from the Xamarin.Forms github to enable a custom `CarouselPageRenderer` implementation. All of this is in the github sample but hopefully this spells it out more clearly for future visitors.

Note2: I would like to stress that the true behavior we were trying to achieve is probably best done with a NavigationPage as this allows us to easily pop and push any and all pages at any time without having to address the swipe issue. That being said, hopefully this solution serves to aid anyone who need this behavior on a `CarouselPage`.